# push value with key into array at key = value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, pdo

I have a database with multiply users and there position data. I put them in an array like below

```
id--username--lat-----lng
1 | user1  |  56.86 | 7.85
2 | user2  |  48.3  | 9.323
3 | user3  |  83.22 | 84.2
etc...
```

The array $users looks something like:

```
$users = Array( [0] => ( [id] => 1[0] => 1[username] => user1[1] => user1[lat] => 56.86[2] => 56.86[lng] => 7.85[3] => 7.85)
[1] => ( [id] => 2[0] => 2[username] => user2[1] => user2[lat] => 48.3[2] => 48.3[lng] => 9.323[3] => 9.323)
[2] => ( [id] => 3[0] => 3[username] => user3[1] => user3[lat] => 83.22[2] => 83.22[lng] => 84.2[3] => 84.2))
```

I calculate the distance with the lat and lng from each user with mylat and mylng.
Then I want to push the value $distn into the array $users at the position/key id with the value of the users id but I dont know how:

```
    foreach ($users as $row) { //for each user in database calculate the distance and set it to the variable $distn

    $dist = 0.0;
        $x1 = $mylng;
        $x2 = $row['lng'];
        $y1 = $mylat;
        $y2 = $row['lat'];

        $dist = acos(sin($x1=deg2rad($x1))*sin($x2=deg2rad($x2))+cos($x1)*cos($x2)*cos(deg2rad($y2) - deg2rad($y1)))*(6378.137);
        $distn = FLOOR ( ROUND($dist,1) * 2 ) / 2 ;

      push $distn into $users where id=row['id'] // this is just a sample not real code

    }
```

So that the array should look like this now:

```
$users = Array( [0] => ( [id] => 1[0] => 1[dist] => 3.0[1] => 3.0[username] => user1[2] => user1[lat] => 56.86[3] => 56.86[lng] => 7.85[4] => 7.85)
[1] => ( [id] => 2[0] => 2[dist] => 1.5[1] => 1.5[username] => user2[2] => user2[lat] => 48.3[3] => 48.3[lng] => 9.323[4] => 9.323)
[2] => ( [id] => 3[0] => => 3[dist] => 1.0[1] 1.0[username] => user3[2] => user3[lat] => 83.22[3] => 83.22[lng] => 84.2[4] => 84.2))
```

The value $distn is added with the key "dist" after the key "id" with the value of each user.
If this works I want to sort the array so the user with the lowest "dist" is shown first:

```
user3 1km distance
user2 1.5km distance
user1 3km distance
```

How can I do all that? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You have 3 of the exact same question.  STOP!

Comment: AbraCadaver I have 2 questions that are a bit same but this is something other! I want To know how I can push the value into the array at a specific key. T hat has nothing to do with my old questions!

Comment: Well now you know how to do it, see below.

Comment: Thanks I try it tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, use the `$key => $value` syntax for `foreach()`:

```
foreach ($users as $key => $row) {
    // code
    $users[$key]['dist'] = $distn;
}
```

For the sorting, I would extract the column and sort the original by that:

```
array_multisort(array_column($users, 'dist'), SORT_ASC, $users);
```

Also, since you're using an associative array consider:

```
$users = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: It worked finally! Thanks